# SQL Server Separate Overlapping Dates and Street Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with multiple *Street Names with Street Number* ranges and date ranges. The problem is that there are some overlapping not only in dates, but in street numbers too, and I need to split it. I saw a question about how to split it by Dates ([SQL Server separate overlapping dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795907/sql-server-separate-overlapping-dates#)), but my problem seems to be slightly different but much more complex.

For Example, this is how it looks right now:

```
StartDate   EndDate     StreetName      StreetNumberLow     StreetNumberHigh        Value 
2017/1/1    2017/3/31   MyStreet        5                   7                       1729 
2017/4/1    2020/12/31  MyStreet        5                   7                       1763
2017/1/1    2017/12/31  MyStreet        1                   11                      1729
2018/1/1    2020/12/31  MyStreet        1                   11                      18128
```

How it should look:

```
StartDate   EndDate     StreetName      StreetNumberLow     StreetNumberHigh        Value
2017/1/1    2017/3/31   MyStreet        5                   7                       1729
2017/4/1    2020/12/31  MyStreet        5                   7                       1763
2017/1/1    2017/12/31  MyStreet        1                   4                       1729
2017/1/1    2017/12/31  MyStreet        8                   11                      1729
2018/1/1    2020/12/31  MyStreet        1                   4                       18128
2018/1/1    2020/12/31  MyStreet        8                   11                      18128
```

As you can see, there was two overlaps in Street Number and Dates, so I need to split it. Can someone please help me on finding the solution to this? Thank you

EDITED: Another case example: If I have Street Number range 1 - 11 from January to June with Value 100, and Street Number range 5 - 7 from March to December with Value 200, then the result should be as follows: Street Number range 1 - 11 from January to February with Value 100, Street Number ranges 1 - 4 with Value 100, 5 - 7 with Value 200 and 8 - 11 with Value 100 from March to June, and Street Number range 5 - 7 from July to December with Value 200

Comment: Can you Please give more details. I am not sure what you mean by Split them?. where does the New High and Low number come from. What are you trying to split exactly?

Comment: as it overlaps in addresses 1 to 11, in the same dates, I need to split the address range into 1 - 4, 5 - 7 and 8 - 11

Comment: Can you elaborate on the conditions of overlap? from the looks of the result you are saying row 3 and row 1 overlap, but it is not clear what the conditions of splitting are because the dates between row 1 and 3 are different

Comment: Row 1 and 3 overlaps, but doesn't really matters, because they have the same Value. In the other hand, rows 2 and 3 overlaps, and that does matters, because if I look for the value of 5 in July 2017, I have two possible values for it: 1763 and 1729, and that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please update your question's sample data with the 1763 and 1729 values that you are referring to. Also, how does the dates interfer with "overlap" what if only a portion of the date overlaps, would that then spawn another row just to cover the dates it doesn't overlap?

Comment: The sample data is with 1763 and 1729 examples. I'll add the case you mentioned to the example, so let me know if that makes sense to you. Thanks!

Comment: @HenryLu I added the example in the EDITED section. Thanks

Comment: I still unable to understand what you are trying to accomplish, Sorry